# How to get polygon coordinates of a searched place in GoogleMaps?

Tags: polygon, google-maps, google-maps-api

[image]

When you search a town on GoogleMaps , it shows a highlighted polygon area. How can i get coordinates of that polygon?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Google does not allow access to their raw data. However, town boundaries should be available on openstreetmap as well.

Comment: Not via the Google Maps API? https://developers.google.com/maps

Comment: i couldnt find a way either for osm , how can i do same thing on osm?